# Customise jQuery Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to do the following:

1) Open the first box by default &
2) Close the box when clicked. Right now it closes & re-opens instantly.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/

```
    (function($) {

  var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add this line after the `click` handler:

```
$('.accordion > dt > a').first().trigger('click');
```

2) Add this line at the second line of the `click` handler:

```
if ($(this).parent().next().is(":visible")) return false;
```

So:

```
$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    if ($(this).parent().next().is(":visible")) return false;
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    return false;
});
$('.accordion > dt > a').first().trigger('click');
```

updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/4/)

Comment: It don't close the thingy on click

Comment: I like yours better than mine

Comment: @Shiala Why thank you.  Your answer is how I would logically want to do it.  But there was a simpler solution available.

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2hmzcgqm/3/
Save the visibility and then it will determine if it has to show or hide base on that

```
var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();

  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    var $dd = $(this).parent().next(),
        isShown = $dd.is(':visible');

    allPanels.slideUp();

    $dd[isShown ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']();

    return false;
  });

  $('.accordion > dt > a').get(0).click();
```